# How can I customize badCredentialsException message when the password does not match?

Tags: spring-security

> By default the AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider throws a BadCredentialsException if a username is not found or the password is incorrect. Setting this property to false will cause UsernameNotFoundExceptions to be thrown instead for the former

Now, if the username is incorrect, I can throw the `UserNameNotFoundException` by setting the `HideUserNotFoundExceptions` property to false.

But,during the password validation process, a BadCredentialsException is thrown by the DaoAuthenticationProvider

```java
throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
```

Can I customize the message instead of using this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials")?